# 16GB SanDisk USB drive became 2x64MB

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, u3

I used a SanDisk Cruzer Contour 16GB USB 2.0 drive for almost 5 years, but one day it just turned into two 64MB drives. Windows even recognize two separate devices

[image: screenshot]

Tried formatting, messing with GParted in Ubuntu. I also tried to install U3 functionality, which I removed long ago, no luck. Is it possible to fix the drive?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once before with a flash drive, and came to the conclusion that it just went bad. If it shows up this way in gparted, it's a hardware issue. Flash memory does have a limited number of writes, so a "5 year" old drive could have simply experienced too many writes.

Comment: 5 years is good mileage on a thumb drive. Time to replace!

Answer (score 1):

The drive's firmware has gone out to lunch.  If there is any hope you would have to consult the manufacturer, but they tend not to provide much help for 5 year old $10 products, so it's time to throw it out and get a new one.

Comment: I highly doubt it was $10 for a 16GB flash drive in 2007. More like $50! :)

Comment: It was $80, Cruzer Contour isn't the cheapest line :D And on the package it said 5 year warranty, but scumbag retailer doesn't give a sh...